# Indent text without using trivlist

Tags: indentation

Quite a lot environments which change margins (e.g. center, quote, addmargin from KOMA) use internally `trivlist`. This has some drawbacks, e.g., when the list is directly between two sectioning commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{a section}
%a
\begin{quote}
\subsection*{An important quote}
blalbla
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

e.g., gives the well known and feared error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

So I tried to extract from trivlist the code that does the indentation and drop all the label related code and came up with the following code. My question is:

**Is there some obvious flaw?**

(It looks so simple that I wonder why it doesn't exist yet!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{indentation}[2][0pt]%#1=right indentation
  {\par
   \begingroup
   \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne  
   \leftmargin=#2\relax
   \rightmargin=#1\relax
   \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin\relax
   \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
   \advance \@totalleftmargin \leftmargin
   \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
   \@setpar{{\@@par}}}
  {\global\advance\@listdepth\m@ne\endgroup\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
  \lipsum[1]
   \[a=b\]
\begin{itemize}
\item blabla
\end{itemize}


\section{abc}
\begin{indentation}[\leftmargini]{\leftmargini}
\subsection{abc}
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{itemize}
  \item blub
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Does it work?
   \end{enumerate} 
 \end{itemize}
 \[a=b\]
 \lipsum[2-3]

 \begin{indentation}{0pt}
  \centering
  \lipsum[1]
 \end{indentation}
\end{indentation}

\end{document}
```

## Edit

I take back the "doesn't exist yet". I just found on CTAN http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/misc/indent.sty, which contains an almost identical definition (even with the same name). The only difference is that my code changes `\@listdepth` as I wanted to keep the relation of indent for nested lists.

Comment: bravo for daring to escape from the `list` straitjacket.  it's an oversimplification to think that *everything* is just another form of list.  (so many reported bugs for `amsthm` are simply the result of `list` being too restrictive.)  i haven't actually tried compiling this, but from reading the code, i didn't see anything obvious either.  i will try to find time to give it a workout.

Comment: why do you want a subsection heading inside a quote?

Comment: The obvious flaw is having a `\subsection` inside a `quote`. It makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In real life I would probably use a KOMA class and `\minisec`. Beside this the example should only show that it is dangerous to start one of the environments based on trivlist with a sectioning command. Also I get quite often the request to indent some part of a document and then fight against the additional list spacing and the `\@noitemerr`.

Comment: @egreg: And what would you use as title of quote if you want to prevent that there is a page break after it?

Comment: Surely not `\subsection*`. I would define a `titledquote` environment, with a proper setting for avoiding page breaks (`\nopagebreak` might be sufficient). Abusing sectioning commands is wrong to begin with.

Comment: I should say starting sections inside a lower level environment should be a non-aim, so while your code looks probably safe enough I'm not sure I agree with the premise that it's needed:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm starting to regret that I used this example to demonstrate the problems with `\trivlist`;-). But perhaps this one is more convincing: In this question the internal center environment is the culprit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237528/tikz-label-over-path-flips. If I redefine center to `\renewenvironment{center}{\begin{indentation}{0pt}\centering}{\end{indentation}}` the problem disappears.

Comment: Section headings in quotes will be rare, but it is in the nature of a quote that we don't have control over its contents. An extended quote may well contain some sort internal of section headings.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the % from line number 4 of your code, the error goes away. 
A \section always has to contain some text.

Comment: Sorry but this is not an answer. I know that the error goes away if I uncomment the "a". But the point of my question it to avoid the error in the other case.

Comment: If you want to have an empty \section, put something like ~\\ in it:
\begin{document}
 \section{a section}
 ~\\
 \begin{quote} ...

It won't appear int the pdf.

Comment: My question is not about document based work arounds but about a general solution. Please check my reputation before continuing to give me such advices.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.
Then you should define your own section command:
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mysection[2][\DefaultOpt]{%
 \def\DefaultOpt{#2}%
 \section[#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
 \mysection[Empty section]{
  %a
  \begin{quote}
   \subsection*{An important quote}
   blalbla
  \end{quote} 
 }
\end{document}

Comment: You are again offering a solution for one document. And I certainly don't want to put the whole section text in an argument.