# First appearance of \begin{enumerate} conflicts with \section{...}

Tags: enumerate, incompatibility, sections-paragraphs

I have observed that a `\begin{enumerate}` before the first appearance of an e.g. `\section{...}` environment causes problems.   Why do I need to move `\begin{enumerate}` right before the first `\item`?

Overall, there is some sort of conflict between the first appearance of `\begin{enumerate}` and the first appearance of `\section{...}`.   Is there a rule of thumb I missed about Latex or Latex2e?

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/indent-text-without-using-trivlist

Comment: Your question is not very clear. But `\section` should never be inside an `enumerate` environment, if that is what you mean? Since a list environment should only be a list of `\item` then naturally `\begin{enumerate}` has to be before the first `\item`

Comment: `\section` is no environment

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear but I suspect that you want an enumerated list in each section which starts from where the previous section's list left off, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzzz}
\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{enumerate}

\section{Zzzzzz}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item aaaa
\item bbbb
\end{enumerate}

\section{Zzzzzzz}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item aaaaa
\item bbbbb
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

A list such as `enumerate` is a list of items, each prefixed by `\item` so you can't have a section heading in a list, and naturally the first command after `\begin{enumerate}` has to be `\item`.

I used the `enumitem` package here to simplify starting the lists at numbers other than 1, via its `resume` option.