# Indentation superfunction LaTeX

Tags: spacing, indentation

There are a lot of questions on here that are about indentation and I feel like what most people are looking for is something similar to the following.

It would be nice to have some sort of function to call, `\indent{}`, so that everything sounded by `{}` was placed one tab length from the left margin.

Also, the ability to call this function inside itself, so that, for instance,

```
 %this is an example of what I am talking about.
\indent{
    textbody1

    \indent{
        textbody2
    }
}
```

resulted in the entirety of `textbody2` being one tab unit away from the entirety of `textbody1`'s left margin.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `tabbing`?

Comment: @azetina see edit.

Comment: You can do this with a variety of boxes as well as with tabular environments.

Comment: `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}`?

Answer (score 5):

Since `\indent` is already used, I used `\myindent` and used `\mytab` for the "tab" size.  Pretty much any length will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\mytab}
\setlength{\mytab}{\bibindent}

\newcommand{\myindent}[1]% #1 = text to be indented
{\ifvmode\else\par\fi
\bgroup\advance\leftskip by \mytab
#1\egroup\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\myindent{\lipsum[2]
  \myindent{\lipsum[3]}
  \lipsum[4]
}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good approach although I would define, like you rightfully suggested, a new length to avoid compilation issues.

Comment: Sure, why not?  -----

Comment: Wonderful :) Much better IMHO.

Comment: So easy looking.  I got jealous that I had not thought of that.

Comment: This won't work if the content contains a list (including quote and center) or verbatim material. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/indent-text-without-using-trivlist

Answer (score 5):

You can use lists, with the help of `enumitem` for setting parameters more easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{subindent}[1][0.5in]
  {\itemize[label={},leftmargin=#1,nosep]\item\relax}
  {\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
  \begin{subindent}
  \lipsum[3]
    \begin{subindent}[1in]
    \lipsum[4]
    \end{subindent}
  \lipsum[5]
  \end{subindent}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]