# Weird "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." when using itemize inside quote

Tags: errors, itemize, pandoc

For the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Lesson Design}

\begin{quote}
\subsection{Overview}

\textbf{Questions}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  How do we design lessons?
\end{itemize}

\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./foo.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   H
        ow do we design lessons?
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

when I run `pdflatex -halt-on-error FILENAME.tex`.

If I remove the lines with `\section{Lesson Design}`, `\subsection{Overview}` or `\textbf{Questions}` I don't see the error anymore. The example is part of a Pandoc output.

### How I end up here

I have

```
<h1 class="maintitle">Lesson Design</h1>
<blockquote class="objectives">
  <h2>Overview</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <strong>Teaching:</strong> 10 min
      <br>
      <strong>Exercises:</strong> 0 min
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <strong>Questions</strong>
      <ul>

    <li><p>How do we design lessons?</p>
</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <strong>Objectives</strong>
      <ul>

    <li><p>Describe the reverse instructional design process.</p>
</li>

    <li><p>Describe the purpose and implementation of formative assessments.</p>
</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</blockquote>
```

that is render by web browsers, after apply CSS, as

[image: Render of HTML]

I end up using `blockquote` tag because Pandoc removes `div` tag.

Comment: why do you want to start a new subsection within a `quote`? Just move that up a line, so that it is outside.

Comment: Because I want a box and Pandoc removes `div`s when converting to LaTeX.

Comment: What do you mean by a box?

Comment: (but I agree with @RunarTrollet)

Comment: I update the question mentioning how I end up there.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/indent-text-without-using-trivlist

Comment: I think you should have a look at http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox